# Google Cloud Functions sometimes doesn't find @google-cloud/* dependencies although the buildpack builds and runs fine in Docker on local

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, build, google-cloud-functions, dependencies

I am deploying a Google Cloud function and it fails to deploy because **it sometimes doesn't find the module `@google-cloud/pubsub` and when it finds it, it instead fails on a transitive dependency from the pubsub package**. I have had this with `@google-cloud/storage` as well and never managed to solve it.

See the logs screenshot below in this post for an example of the issue. It shows two consecutive deployments.

- In the first deployment, the `@google-cloud/pubsub` is not found although it is listed in package.json
- In the second deployment, the `pubsub` package is found(!), but then instead it fails on the transitive dependency `google-gax`.

**Things I tried**

- Deploy using Google Cloud Build, hooked up to my github repo  *(deplyoment fails)*
- Deploy from local command line. See script target `deployAnalyzer` in package.json below. *(deployment fails with same errors a Google Cloud Builds)*
- Deploy the function locally to the functions framework. See script target `devFunctionAnalyzer` below. *(Deplyoment works and the function can be invoked)*
- Build locally using `pack` to repeat the same build procedure as Google Cloud Build. *Result: Image builds and runs fine!*

*In short: It work fine locally,* both in the Functions Framework and running the docker image built using the google nodejs buildpack.

**The Full Code**

Work in progress: https://github.com/aweijnitz/ornitho-de-monitor

Minimalistic repo with one dependency, that fails with the same error: https://github.com/aweijnitz/cloud-functions-dependency-test-01/tree/main

**EDIT**
Added link to stripped down repo that illustrates the problem without all the application code. Just a single dependency now.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ornitho-de-monitor",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Collect latest interesting observations from ornitho.de",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "devFunctionAnalyzer": "npx functions-framework --target=analyzeObservations --signature-type=event",
    "devFunctionNotifier": "npx functions-framework --target=notifyAll --signature-type=event",
    "buildCloudRunContainer": "gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/ornitho-de-monitor/ornitho-de-scraper",
    "deployCloudRunContainer": "gcloud run deploy ornitho-de-scraper --region=europe-west6 --image gcr.io/ornitho-de-monitor/ornitho-de-scraper --platform managed",
    "deployAnalyzer": "gcloud functions deploy analyzeObservations --source=./src --entry-point=analyzeObservations --runtime nodejs12 --memory=256MB --max-instances=3 --trigger-topic=ornitho-bus",
    "deployNotifier": "gcloud functions deploy notifyAll --source=./src --entry-point=notifyAll --runtime nodejs12 --memory=256MB --max-instances=3 --trigger-topic=ornitho-bus",
    "invoke": "gcloud functions call ornitho-de-monitor --data '{\"name\":\"Keyboard Cat\"}'",
    "invokeEncoded": "DATA=$(printf 'Hello!'|base64) && gcloud functions call helloPubSub --data '{\"data\":\"'$DATA'\"}'",
    "viewFunctionLogs": "gcloud functions logs read ornitho-de-monitor",
    "serveTestFile": "cd testdata && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "author": "Anders Weijnitz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.7.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.3",
    "knex": "^0.21.15",
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

**These are the relevant steps from `cloudbuild.yaml`**

```
steps:
  # Retrieve credentials from Fort Knox
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: [ '-c', "gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=ornitho-pubsub --format='get(payload.data)' | tr '_-' '/+' | base64 -d > pubsubkey.json" ]
  # Install dependencies
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: [ 'install' ]
    dir: '.'
  # Run tests
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: [ 'test' ]
    dir: '.'
  # Deploy the notifier function
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - 'functions'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'notifyAll'
      - '--source=./src'
      - '--entry-point=notifyAll'
      - '--runtime=nodejs12'
      - '--memory=128MB'
      - '--max-instances=3'
      - '--trigger-topic=ornitho-bus'
  # Deploy the analyzer function
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - 'functions'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'analyzeObservations'
      - '--source=./src'
      - '--entry-point=analyzeObservations'
      - '--runtime=nodejs12'
      - '--memory=128MB'
      - '--max-instances=3'
      - '--trigger-topic=ornitho-bus'
```

[image]

Comment: I think your package.json is maybe in error with respect to Cloud Functions.  If we read here ... https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing  it seems that (at this date) only Node 8 and Node 10 are supported, but your package.json seems to say that it wants node 12 ...?

Comment: Thanks! Google Cloud Functions support nodejs v12 since a while. It is also stated in the documentation (your link is an older guide for the quick start). That said, I have the same behavior with Node v10.

Support for Node.js v12.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime

Comment: What about a test?  Start from the most basic package.json (for example, the one found associated with a sample Cloud Function in GCP Console) ... and then add the latest versions of your dependencies and nothing else.  See if that package.json exhibits any different outcomes.  Something that is still causing me pause are the dependencies on express.  How confident are you that those are needed?

Comment: I tried that too. Just a two-line program that posts "Hello World" to PubSub. One single dependency. No luck. It is basically identical to the example from Google. Doesn't work. It can't find the module @google-cloud/pubsub

```{
  "name": "cloud-functions-test-01",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --source=./src --entry-point=helloWorld --runtime nodejs12 --memory=256MB --max-instances=3 --trigger-topic=ornitho-bus",
  },
  "author": "AW,
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.7.0"
  }
}```

Comment: I see that your source is in a directory called "./src".  Just checking ... that is where package.json is too? ... Oh ... I then noticed your link to ... https://github.com/aweijnitz/ornitho-de-monitor .... shouldn't package.json be in the src directory otherwise it will be as though you provided no package.json

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The simple answer to your question is "no". :-) There is no relationship between the location of the package.json file and where the code is, as long as you pass the right entry point (see package.json deploy scripts). Also, there is no problem per se with _deploying_ the function. it deploys without problem, but it does not initialize. If Cloud Functions would not be able to find the files in src/, then I would have another error message.

Comment: @Kolban I made a minimalistic repor to showcase the issue. See https://github.com/aweijnitz/cloud-functions-dependency-test-01/tree/main

Comment: @Kolban Actually, I think it might be worth a try. What if it can find my code, because I point to the root in src/, but then gets lost on other dependencies (node_modules)? I will give it a go and report back! Thanks for taking the time to share some thoughts!

Comment: I am still holding on to the possibility that because the ./src folder does not contain your package.json then it is as thought you supplied NO package.json.  If THAT were the case, then when your function starts and tries to to do a require of @google-cloud/pubsub ... it will fail because that wasn't added to your environment as a dependency and that appears to be the text of the error.  For grins, go ahead and copy package.json into the src folder and try it again.  The worst that can happen is no change.

Comment: @Kolban since you have kindly and patiently replied and suggested things to try I did move the package.json to the src/ folder and gave it a go (under much skepsis :-). It did not work at all, since now the package.json file cannot be found at all (not locally and not by google cloud), since it is located in a sub folder, contrary to how node.js and npm expect things to work. Anyway. Wanted to give you the benefit of doubt and give it a go.

Comment: SOLVED! In turns out that the --source parameter should _not_ point to the location of the application source, but to the location of the project root, where package.json resides.

*Bad:* `--source=./src`  

*Good:* `--source=.`

For more details, see https://github.com/aweijnitz/cloud-functions-dependency-test-01

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

In turns out that the `--source` parameter should not point to the location of the application source, but to the location of the project root, where package.json resides. Bad: `--source=./src` Good: `--source=.` .

For more details, see github.com/aweijnitz/cloud-functions-dependency-test-01 –